# How should I write query for this?

Tags: sql

I have a table with the columns Employee_Id, Effective_Date, Salary. ie for each employee, I have multiple records based on when their salary got changed. Now I want to print for each employee the salary with the latest effective_date. How to do this?

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and what specifically went wrong.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
select Employee_Id, Effective_Date, Salary
from employees T
where not exists
    (select 1 from employees TT where TT.Employee_Id = T.Employee_Id and TT.Effective_Date > T.Effective_Date)
```

This may work?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  T.Employee_Id
       ,T.Effective_Date
       ,T.Salary
FROM TableName T INNER JOIN (
                             SELECT Employee_Id
                                    ,MAX(Effective_Date) Last_Date
                             FROM TableName
                             GROUP BY Employee_Id
                             ) LT
ON T.Employee_Id = LT.Employee_Id 
AND T.Effective_Date = LT.Last_Date
```

### Sql Server 2005 and Later

```
SELECT Employee_Id, Effective_Date, Salary
FROM (
     SELECT Employee_Id, Effective_Date, Salary
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_Id ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC) RN
     FROM TableName
     )A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I have one more column called STATUS . It can have value 1 or 2 -> 1 means its a valid entry and 2 means its invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Employee_Id, Effective_Date, Salary
from employees T
where not exists
    (select 1 from employees TT where TT.Employee_Id = T.Employee_Id and TT.Effective_Date > T.Effective_Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM Your_Table_Name_Here 
GROUP BY Employee_Id ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of your table is "Employee_Salary_Table", you might try this:

```
SELECT
    salaries.Employee_ID,
    salaries.Effective_Date,
    salaries.Salary
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Employee_ID,
        Effective_Date,
        Salary,
        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY  Employee_ID
                      ORDER BY      Effective_Date DESC ) N
     FROM
         Employee_Salary_Table
     ) salaries
 WHERE
     salaries.N = 1
```

The inner select ranks all of the employees salary entries by date (starting from the latest). The outer select takes these values where the rank is 1 (the latest).

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify a DB I give a solution for POSTGRES

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (Employee_Id) Employee_Id, Effective_Date, Salary
   FROM TableName 
   ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC
```